# Sagemaker does not recognize Torch

Tags: pip, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, torch

I'm moving my code from Google Colab to AWS Sagemaker. I do `import torch` just after `%pip install torch` and yet I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'`!
I can remember I had used torch on Sagemaker before and I did not get such error!
P.S. I have tried kernel restart.

Comment: Are you using SageMaker Notebooks or Studio? In case of Studio and Data Science kernel it is installed by default. Also, can you do a pip list to see if the package is installed?

Comment: Thank you @RaghuRamesha for your recommendation. I'm using Studio and Data Science 3.0, and it was not installed by default. I faced many inconsistencies in Sagemaker Studio compared to when I used Google Colab. No solutions on the internet worked for me. I deleted all the resources to the domain and created a new one from scratch.

Comment: Studio has a pytorch kernel you can use that which comes preinstalled with torch.